# window.location call popup up empty dialog on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, popup, messagebox, window.location

on a web page i am trying to redirect the browser to another page on the same site.
the code is very simple for that:

```
window.location = "/path1/path2"
```

on safari - both windows as well as mac - a message box containing only the text

```
"http://domain.com"
```

comes up.

I have tried different ways of specifying this: location.href, windows.assign(...) ... and the all have the same behavior.

Did any of you see this? and do you have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for you help.

i found the problem. Before setting window.location somewhere in the call chain one function would make an ajax request.

It seem that due to some changes the request now takes longer then before. So if the location was changed during the ajax req., the empty message box would appear.

Memi.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/should-i-use-window-navigate-or-document-location-in-javascript). You should use:

```
location.href = 'url';
```

Comment: that did not work either :(
i have tried different ways, but they all failed

Comment: location="url" or location.href="url" work identically on all browsers I have ever tried

Answer (score 0):

you should show the complete code.
For example THIS bad code

```
<a href="javascript:window.open()">Click</a>
```

will show [OBJECT] when clicked.

If your script is just

```
<script>
window.location='someurl';
</script>
```

then there is something else going on - I have just test this in Safari on my Mac

```
<script>
window.location='http://www.google.com'
</script>
```