# PhoneGap Android back button needs to be pressed twice

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

When I navigate to a second page and try to go back using the default back button that every android device has, it seems as though the first time I tap it, nothing happens. I have to tap it a second time. Anyone have any idea why this happens?

I'm not sure what more information I need to provide. If you need more info please request specifically what you need and I will try to edit the question.

Edit: my main activity extends DroidGap and only has the one method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

I think I'm narrowing down on the problem. On the second page, there are a list of anchor tags that perform a css animation when clicked.

This jsfiddle isn't doing the animation for whatever reason but here is the relevant markup, css and javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/7fdQu/

Comment: How does your main activity looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on in background but there is a definite for it ....

you can program the back button in Android there is a code for it. The phonegap fires a event "***backbutton***" in Android.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    window.location.href = 'URL';
}
```

Ref:

1. [Should I use window.navigate or document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/should-i-use-window-navigate-or-document-location-in-javascript)
2. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton