# Calling href in Callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-callback

I have a anchor tag in my page for logout.

```
<a href="/logout/" id="lnk-log-out" />
```

Here I am showing a Popup for confirmation with jQuery UI dialog.

***If user click Yes from dialog it has to execute the link button's default action, I mean href="/logout".***

***If No clicked a Popup box should be disappeared.***

jQuery Code

```
 $('#lnk-log-out').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var logOffDialog = $('#user-info-msg-dialog');

            logOffDialog.html("Are you sure, do you want to Logout?");
            logOffDialog.dialog({
                title: "Confirm Logout",
                height: 150,
                width: 500,
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Yes': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        return true;
                    },
                    'No': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

> **The problem is I am not able to fire anchor's href when User click YES.**

***How can we do this?***

**Edit:** Right now I managed in this way

```
'Yes': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        window.location.href = $('#lnk-log-out').attr("href");
                    }
```

Comment: That seems pretty close to my answer! If you're using the "href", you don't even need to close the dialogue first.

Comment: Hey @Murali - is there a reason there's no tick for an answer here? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the anonymous function called when 'Yes' is fired, you want to do the following instead of just returning true:

1. Grab the href (you can get this easily using `$('selector').attr('href');`)
2. Perform your `window.location.href` to the url you grabbed in point 1

If you want the `a` tag to just do it's stuff, remove any `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()`. Here I have provided two different ways :)

**Don't** use `document.location`, use `window.location.href` instead. You can see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/should-i-use-window-navigate-or-document-location-in-javascript).

Your code in the 'Yes' call should look something like, with your code inserted of course:

```
'Yes': function () {
            // Get url
            var href = $('#lnk-log-out').attr('href');
            // Go to url
            window.location.href = href;
            return true; // Not needed
     }, ...
```

**Note**: Thanks to Anthony in the comments below: use `window.location.href = ...` instead of `window.location.href()`, because it's **not** a function!

Comment: `window.location.href` is a string property, not a function. It should be `window.location.href = href;`, not `window.location.href(href);`.

Comment: Also will add Anthony's explanation to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in many of my projects so i suggest `window.location.href`

```
'Yes': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                         window.location.href="your url"    
                        return true;
                    },
```