# How to prepend a https to url on click - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into a situation whereby i have to enable https when a user click on a button.

my current url is as follows: myurl.com

i have to do the following:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){

// change url to https://myurl.com

});
```

My current button's html:

```
<button class="btn" data-statsopt_noninteraction="" data-statsopt_value="" data-statsopt_label="login" data-statsaction="account-actions" data-statscategory="header-events">LOG IN</button>
```

Any help would much be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you wish to do a redirect here? Or is your button really a submit input element, and you want to change the form target?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/

Comment: i dont want any re-direct..my issue is only fixed if the current url is an https when doing the onclick

Comment: _i dont want any re-direct_....then you can do it with some tweaking at your serverside.

Comment: Righto, I'd be inclined to swap the button for a link - causing the browser to go to a new page is what links are for!

Comment: i currently have a script in .NET that is supposed to change the http to https..but it doesn't work. The issue seems to be fixed when i manually add the https to the url and then click on the login button

Comment: _that is supposed to change the http to https_ - you may need to elaborate on that. Change what http? In the URL of the page? In the URL of a form? In a hidden element?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** to replace current protocol `http://` with `https://`:

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){
    location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
});
```

or better to check if your current URL is `https://` or not then redirect the page:

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){
    if (location.href.indexOf("https://") == -1) {
        location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is causing a re-direct..which i dont want :(

Comment: A URL redirect is a web server function that sends a user from one URL to another which is your requirement in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "https://myurl.com";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attaching a JS-only action only to a scriptable element (a button in this case ) is a no-no for accessibility. By doing so you actually prevent people who use a non-supporting user-agent from accessing your content. You should add a `noscript` element:

```
<button id="js-http-action">HTTPS</button>
<noscript>
   <a href="https://yoururl/">HTTPS</a>
</noscript>
```

In a textual browser such as Lynx this will be greatly appreciated by users. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){

// change url to https://myurl.com
window.location.href='https://myurl.com';

});
```

Comment: Please elaborate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){    
  var str = document.URL     
  location.href = str.replace('http','https');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var url = window.location.href.replace(/http/, 'https');
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: I'd anchor the protocol regex to the start of the string, otherwise it is possible to have some unintended side-effects `;-)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".mybutton").click(function () {
    url = "www.myurl.com";
    url = 'http://' + url;
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to format your code - there's a button for it in the UI. _Personally_ I tend to suggest that there's no value in answering a question that's already got five near-identical answers, unless your contribution adds something new.