# Window.location not working in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, php, forms, internet-explorer

```
   function complete()
    {
     updateUserData(); 

     window.location = "/getans.php";
    }

    <input type="button"  id="finish" onClick="complete();" >
```

Unable to redirect user to another page in IE..but it works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: No There is no such error!

Comment: Take a look to this stac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/should-i-use-window-navigate-or-document-location-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this JSBin http://jsbin.com/coqinunacu/1/edit?html,js

```
document.createElement("input").complete
```

`complete` is an `input` property in IE, so simply renaming click handler will help

or you may also explicitly reference `window.complete`

```
<input type="button" value="click"  id="finish" onclick="window.complete()">
```