# How to direct an if/else statement to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

How do I direct a user to another page if the if statement comes true?

For example, the javascript below. If the login details are correct, I want the user to be directed to another page of the website, for example "#page5".

The code is what I currently have which only notifies the user and then redirects back to my index page. However, I want to direct it them to a specific page of the app.

```
function renderList(tx, results) {
  if (results.rows.length > 0) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Login, Success!');
  } else {
    navigator.notification.alert('Incorrect! Please try again.');
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to mention, I am using j query mobile/phonegap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948227/should-i-use-window-navigate-or-document-location-in-javascript

just use something like that

Comment: Awesome, i'll give it ago.

Answer (score 2):

The global `window` object contains the document that is currently loaded. It has a property called `location` that contains the path of the currently loaded resource. Changing this property loads up the resource at the new path into the current window:

```
   window.location = newURL;
```

This is such a simple operation that using jQuery would only make it more involved:

```
   $(window)[0].location = newURL;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using a one page architecture as I using JQueryMobile, so i'm not using seperate html documents. Therefore, how should I adapt the above to this?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just set the location property to the `#section` value that you would have used to navigate to that section if you were to do it manually.

Comment: window.location = "#page4";

Comment: @Mahdi No problem. Don't forget to up vote and mark as answer. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried, but it says I have to earn a total of 15 reputation before doing so. Sorry, I'm new to the site so I will up vote once I achieve 15 reputation.

Comment: No worries! Take care.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect in JavaScript:

```
 window.location = URL;
```

With `jQuery`

```
$(location).attr('href', URL);
```

Comment: @Wowsk use common sence. Ofc URL is variable... Will check jQuery sec.

Comment: Alright I understand now, what it was implying, sorry.

Comment: Ok guys fixed jQuery. A little different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location="link url";`

This will redirect the current page to the provided url.